# How to complete a form with a select AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to complete a form from a database MySQL with AJAX.

For the moment I have this:

**Script**

```js
function showService(str)
{
    $(function() {
        $("#service").autocomplete({
            source: "getservice.php",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#Nazwa').val(ui.item.Nazwa);
                $('#DATE').val(ui.item.DATE);
                $('#Lczba').val(ui.item.Lczba);
                $('#Laureaci').val(ui.item.Laureaci);
             }
        });
    });
```

This is the select:

```
<select  class="checkonkursu" name="konkursu" onChange="showService(this.value)">
    <option value="">Seleccione un konkursu</option>
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT Nazwa FROM  konkursu ORDER BY Nazwa asc", $conexion);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Id_konkursu'].'">'.$row['Nazwa'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

And here is the code for call to database:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        # conectare la base de datos
        $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "Namedatabae");

    $return_arr = array();
    /* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
    if ($con)
    {
        $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM konkursu);
        /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {

            $row_array['Nazwa']=$row['Nazwa'];
            $row_array['Lczba']=$row['Lczba'];
            $row_array['DATE']=$row['DATE'];
            $row_array['Laureaci']=$row['Laureaci'];

            array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        }
    }

    /* Cierra la conexión. */
    mysqli_close($con);

    /* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    }
?>
```

For sure it is so bad code but I am learning and sorry for it.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What doesn't work? We can help find issues, but it is up to you to tell us what you are looking for. If you want someone to write the code, hire someone. Lookup "how to ask a question" for helpful information on creating a questions that will get answers.

Comment: You should add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page. Is there a typo on `$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM konkursu);` (missing a ") ? and please let PHP show you errors, and get rid of @. EDIT: plus : are you using a mix of mysql_* and mysqli_* ?!

Comment: in your select you have got `mysql_query("SELECT...)` it must be `mysqli_query`

Comment: @OldPadawan i didnt take any error with this :(

Comment: @MancharyManchaary yeah thank you

Comment: @SloanThrasher thank you for the recomendation for hire some person but i want to learn like all... i hope that u never have problems...

Comment: The suggestion to lookup how to ask a question wasn't meant to be snide or mean. It has information that will help you to compose a question that is more likely to get useful answers. We all have to learn....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You are simply wanting to fill a HTML select with the value being the ID of records from your database, and the name being the corresponding name.

The jQuery showService function seems redundant here. You can set the value of the select in your echo of the option, which you have attempted to do. However there is an error in

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Nazwa FROM  konkursu ORDER BY Nazwa asc", $conexion);
```

as Manchary pointed out this should be [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (as mysql is deprecated). But also you have your arguments mixed up so the line should be :

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Nazwa FROM konkursu ORDER BY Nazwa ASC")
```

It common practice to rewrite this as

```
$sql = "SELECT Nazwa FROM konkursu ORDER BY Nazwa ASC";
$qry = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

So in the event your query should fail, you will receive a (not always useful) error message. But something to point you to the problem at least.

I have written the select with general english language in a hope it is still useful to you while also helping others.

```
<select  class="foo" name="selector">
<option value="#">Select an Option</option>
<?php

    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>".$row['Name']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```